# JSLint complaints when calculating squares as in a * a

Tags: javascript, jslint

When I write this Javascript code:

```
var a = 2;
var aSquared = a * a;
```

JSLint marks `a * a` as a *weird assignment*. It marks just the product, not the assignment (I'm using Netbeans 7.3).

I know I can use `Math.pow(a, 2)` but this kind of calculation takes place in a tight iterative numerical computation and [the difference is relevant](http://jsperf.com/math-pow-vs-product).

Is it really weird to calculate squares this way?

Comment: When i try you code on http://www.jslint.com/, I don't get any errors. Do you use any non-default settings?

Comment: 1.  I can't reproduce this on jslint.com either, 2. jslint.com is crap - it concentrates too much on style issues (e.g. indentation) over true coding errors.  JSHint is much better IMHO.

Comment: I'm getting this message in the Netbeans editor. I recently upgraded to 7.3 and started to get this sort of messages.

Comment: it's worth repeating that the warnings issued by jsLint, jsHint and by Netbeans are just that -- warnings. They're not actual errors, and you are free to ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd just ignore it -- it's just a warning, and you know the code is good, so... meh.

But if you really want to avoid the warning, you could try wrapping some brackets around it:

```
var aSquared = (a * a);
```

Or you could replace your code with something like this:

```
function squared(a) { return a *= a; }
```

Comment: I agree. But those messages are distracting!